# Company information (address etc .) for QGIS

Tags: qgis, commercial

In order to make a donation for developing QGIS, I have to submit to my company department all "QGIS" company (company name, address, telephone, commercial registry number ...) information that will be printed on the invoice/receipt.
I search https://www.qgis.org but I can't find any information or email address to ask to.

Comment: What about the data on the donations site? (https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/donations.html)

Comment: I read the box for the bank transfer but it's not enought.

Comment: Contact the [treasurer](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/governance/sponsorship/sponsorship.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with GIS

Comment: StackExchange is in the list of [support](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html) mailing list .